# Show product features in cart summary in Prestashop

Tags: php, html, mysql, prestashop

I am trying to show product features in the cart summary on one page checkout with using below code in `shopping-cart-product-line.tpl` but giving error.

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature name=features}
{if $feature.id_feature == 9}   
{$features.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
{/if} 
{/foreach}
```

Do I need to do anything with `CartController.php`?

Error 
Notice: Undefined index: value in 
path/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 89

Comment: Can you plz add the error  message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
{assign var="features" value=Product::getFrontFeaturesStatic(Context::getContext()->language->id, $product.id_product)} 

{foreach $features as $feature}
{if $feature.id_feature == 6}
<div>{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</div>
{/if}

{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `{$feature.value}` instead of `{$features.value}` :

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature name=features}
{if $feature.id_feature == 9}   
{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
{/if} 
{/foreach}
```

No need to override the controller or the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the features value by modifying code in one of the following file (this depends upon the type of checkout you are using in your store):

```
/controllers/front/OrderOpcController.php (Edit for OPC)
```

or

```
/controllers/front/OrderController.php (Edit for five step)
```

The 'value' field is missing from $features array, you can use the following function to fetch features data for any product.

```
 Product::getFeaturesStatic($id_product);
```